# syntax error on token(s) misplaced construct(s) in android

Tags: android

I am new in android development and i need help with the slideshow animator in eclipse.I have a syntax error on token(s) misplaced construct(s) in public boolean onCreateOptionMenu and in publicVoid onStart.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String Home,Gallery,Services,Aboutus; 




   Activity context;
   AnimatorSet set;
   ImageView imgView;
   int imgResources[]={R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4,R.drawable.img5};

int index=0;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





    context=this;



    Button viewHome= (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    viewHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent= new Intent(v.getContext(),onClickListener.class);
            startActivity(intent);

}



**public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


    return true;**



    public  void onStart(){
           super.onStart();  
           imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
           set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this,R.animator.slideshow);
           set.setTarget(imgView);    
           set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter(){         
             public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator){
             //repeat animation

                if(index<imgResources.length)
                {
                imgView.setImageResource(imgResources[index]);
                index++;      
             set.start();

                } 
             }

               });
               set.start();

               }

            });
    }
    }
```

Comment: you missed the closing bracket for `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: `setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()` does not end

Comment: Can I ask you another question.. In this code now , the line super.onStart is undefined for the type Object.. why?? what its wrong??

Comment: @user4873976 See my comment. You declare `onStart` for the `OnClickListener`

Comment: @StenSoft please explain me more if you can with the code for the OnClickListener because it is wrong again.. thanks!

Comment: Try using strict indention. You should see then clearly when the `OnClickListener` does not end. (It's just before `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu`)